# Codename One overdraw

Tags: codenameone

I have a Form that it’s very slow to load. I saw that Android has an overdraw debugging tool: all the Components of the Form (that uses Tabs) are red, so they are overdrawn multiple times.

I don’t know which actions I can do to debug, solve or mitigate this issue.

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the performance inspector tool in the simulator to see what's drawing. When you run it you can see a tree indicating what's drawn by each component then figure out why we draw a specific component.

E.g. the form would normally draw its background. But if the tabs are defined as opaque and take up 100% of the space (no margin) then they should block the drawing of the form.

Notice that overdraw will just create slight sluggishness not necessarily "slow" performance.